# XOR -Is it possible to prove that if A=C⊕B then B=C⊕A and C=A⊕B using Boolean algebra only?

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, computer-science

If you write out the truth tables then it's pretty simple but I was wondering if there was a nicer proof using Boolean algebra only

Comment: Like $A\oplus B = C\oplus B\oplus  B = C\oplus 0 = C$?

Comment: Sorry I don't get what you mean

Comment: I think math.SE fits better for this question.

Comment: What Paul proposed is: take A=C⊕B and add ⊕B on both sides of the equation.  You get A⊕B=C,

Comment: Ahh ok, thanks, now I get it. Can't believe it was that simple :)